# Marching cubes leaving holes in the mesh

Tags: c#, unity, voxels, marching-cubes

Hi I'm trying to reproduce [GPU Gems 3 chapter 1 (Generating Complex Procedural Terrains Using the GPU)](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html) and so far I managed the basics... Now I'm betting some strange output.

I started with the suggested -ws.y to generate a plane. Then when I moved to the noise I noticed some holes in the mesh. [But unlike this previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69106/marching-cubes-density-function-noise-sampling-leaves-holes-in-plane).

The noise mesh:
[image]

So I decided to try something more simple, 3 tubes:
x^2+y^2-2
[image: Everything seems ok on this one]

x^2+z^2-2
[image: Oh boy...]

y^2+z^2-2
[image: And finally]

I would assume there is some problem with the z axis. But I can seem to figure out what.
My function to get the triangles vertex positions also seems ok...

```
Vector3 vertexAlongEdge(int edge, Voxel v){
    Vector3 result=new Vector3(0,0,0);

    Vector3 p1=v.vertexes[edges [edge, 0]];
    Vector3 p2=v.vertexes[edges [edge, 1]];
    float v1 = density (p1);
    float v2 = density (p2);
    if (Mathf.Abs (isoLevel - v1) < 0.00001)
        return p1;
    if (Mathf.Abs (isoLevel - v2) < 0.00001)
        return p2;
    if (Mathf.Abs (v1 - v2) < 0.00001)
        return p1;

    float m = Mathf.Abs((isoLevel - v1) / (v1 - v2));
    result.x = p1.x + m * (p2.x - p1.x);
    result.y = p1.y + m * (p2.y - p1.y);
    result.z = p1.z + m * (p2.z - p1.z);

    return result;
}
```

The only thing I can think of right now is an error in my table with the edges for each case.
Please help.

Comment: Any chance back-face culling is the issue? Unity expects front-facing tris to have their points in clockwise order.

Comment: if that was the case they would be visible from the outside I suppose. But they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I had a wrong value on the vertex for an edge. My edge table said that for the edge 10 the vertex were 2 and 4 when they should be 2 and 6.

Thank you for your time.